# Creating temp directory on server

Tags: php, linux, webserver

Is it possible to create a temporary directory on a hosting server with the same functionality as the tmp folder in the root directory?

I need a second tmp folder to temporary store files that I'm uploading to another web service. I want to avoid `unlink()` functions or cron jobs for deleting files.

Comment: Have you considered tmpfile() ?

Comment: Yes but from my understanding it creates a temporary file in the tmp folder. I want to create a new tmp directory or use tmpfile() to specify where to save the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can .... using [System::mktemp](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/core.pear.system.mktemp.php)

```
$tempfile = System::mktemp("prefix");       
$tempdir  = System::mktemp("-d prefix");
$tempfile = System::mktemp();
$tempfile = System::mktemp("-t /var/tmp prefix");
```

Or you can run the command using exec

```
  mktemp  make temporary dirname
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the command but get `mktemp: too many templates
` I'm using SSH. I'm on shared hosting and can't run command directly.

Comment: You have so many restrictions `shared hosting` , no `unlink` , no `cron` .. this might be difficult ...

Comment: I can use `unlink` and `cron`. I asked my host (hostgator) how to run the command and they enabled `ssh`. I'm using PuTTY to run the command

Comment: I can write a small temp directory manager for you .. if you can use  unlink and cron ....

Comment: well I want to save files that I upload in the temp directory. I'm not sure what the difference is

Comment: How long do you want to save them in the temp directory for ??

Comment: I want to save them until the script is finished executing. I used `unlink()` at the end of the script but decided to use tmp functions instead for security reasons.

Comment: If that is the case PHP takes care of that for you ..... don't run `move_uploaded_file` until you are sure you want to use the file .... if the script execute and you don't move the file .. its automatically delete :)

Comment: the uploading script I use runs `move_uploaded_file` and I have to specify an upload path. `tmp` in the root won't work so i decided to create a new `tmp` folder

Comment: you can still work on the image before you run `move_uploaded_file` ??? you don't need a special tmp file .. on run `move_uploaded_file` if you want to move to final destination .... except you have other requirements